# Reading PGM Images in C

Tags: c, pgm

I am trying to read PGM Images using the following function:

```
typedef struct PGMImage{
    int w;
    int h;
    unsigned char* data;
}GrayImage;

    void ReadPGMImage(char* filename,GrayImage* image)
    {
        int width,height,size,binary,i,j;

        FILE  *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

        if(!fp){
           fprintf(stderr,"Unable to open file in 'r' mode");
           exit(errno);
        }

        readPNMHeader(fp, &width, &height,&binary);

        size = width * height;
        *image = CreateGrayImage(width,height);

        if (!(image->data)){
            fprintf(stderr,"Memory not allocated");
            exit(errno);
        }

        fread((void *)image->data, sizeof(unsigned char), (size_t) size, fp);

        fclose(fp);

        return;
    }
```

The image I am trying to read has these headers:
P2
640 480
255

When I print out the values of certain pixels(rows:400-410,columns:300-310),'205' gets printed for all the pixels whereas the actual values as per Matlab are:

```
  >248  255  255  250  254  254  254  252  252  255
  >255  255  255  255  255  255  255  255  255  255
  >255  255  255  255  255  255  255  255  255  255
  >255  255  255  255  255  255  255  255  255  255
  >255  255  255  255  255  255  255  255  255  255
  >248  247  249  245  251  252  253  252  245  251
  >241  240  243  237  240  244  239  242  243  244
  >235  238  238  237  239  238  239  238  240  242
  >236  233  241  235  236  234  236  239  235  237
  >231  239  231  239  234  234  230  233  233  234
```

Similar code works when I read PPM images. Could someone tell me where I am going wrong?

EDIT:
Final code that works:

```
void ReadPGMImage(char * fileName, GrayImage* image) {
    FILE * fp = NULL;
    char version[100];
    int levels = 0;
    unsigned int w = 0, h = 0;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    int pixdat = 0;



    if( fileName == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Bad file name=%s\n", fileName );
        return;
    }

    fp = fopen(fileName,"rb");
    if( fp == NULL )    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Cannot open file = %s\n", fileName );
        return;
    }


    fscanf(fp,"%s",version);

    SkipComments(fp);
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &w);
    SkipComments(fp);
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &h);
    SkipComments(fp);
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &levels);

    CreateGrayImage(image,w,h);
    image->w = w;
    image->h = h;
    for(i=0;i<w*h;i++) {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &pixdat);
        image->data[i] = pixdat;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return;
}
```

Comment: I guess you should use `fscanf()` instead of `fread()` and have the function parse the numbers and convert to integers to read the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PGM has a decimal representation of the data values, so use fscanf to read the values in:

```
int offset=0;
while(! feof(fp) ){
    fscanf(fp, "%hu", &value);
    image->data[offset++] = value;
}
```

The *%hu* gives you *unsigned short* values (i.e. 0..65535 value), since PGM values can be shorts as well as bytes. On this basis, when you allocate the memory for the data, make sure to use:

```
 x->data = (unsigned short*)malloc( width * height * sizeof(unsigned short))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code so far seems to be fine with one little exception.

I think the following code line is the cause of the problem

```
*image = CreateGrayImage(width,height);
```

Here you assign the pointer returned by CreateGrayImage() to *image which overwrites the content of the structure.

I assume you want to pass the pointer returned by CreateGrayImage() to the caller of CreateGrayImage(). In this case you need to change the function declaration of ReadPGMImage() to the following:

```
void ReadPGMImage(char* filename,GrayImage** image)
```

Then it should work as you expect.